# Split an image and save new images, VB

Tags: vb.net, image

Is it possible to load a 900X900 pixels image from a specific folder, split it with VB into 9  300X300 pixels images and save those images in the same folder as the original one with names from "1" to "9" ?
Like:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Thanks.

Comment: please provide any attempt(s) so far, as it *seems* that you are yet to attempt anything.

Comment: Chris has right .. it's a duplicate question .. but is in C# not in VB

Comment: try that ideea : `code` Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < 3
 Dim y As Integer = 0
 While y < 3
  Dim r As New Rectangle(i * (pictureBox1.Image.Width / 3), y * (pictureBox1.Image.Height / 3), pictureBox1.Image.Width / 3, pictureBox1.Image.Height / 3)

  g.DrawRectangle(pen, r)

  list.Add(cropImage(pictureBox1.Image, r))
  System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(y),y - 1)
 End While
 System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i),i - 1)
End While